# why dereferencing on a address gives "invalid indirect" error in golang?

Tags: go, pointers, memory-address, dereference

```
type person struct{
  Name string
  Age int
}

// parameters : (pointer to person struct), which is basically address of person object
func printPerson(p *person) {

  // when we add '*' to a address, then it becomes dereferencing, Hence 
  // I read "*p.Name" as "person object dot Name" and i expect it to give value,
  // I get this error:
  // ./prog.go:20:15: invalid indirect of p.Name (type string)
  // ./prog.go:20:24: invalid indirect of p.Age (type int)
  fmt.Println(*p.Name, *p.Age) // does not works, ERROR THROWN

  // But this works perfectly
  // I read it as "person address dot name and person address dot age"
  // for me it does not make sense when we say "address dot field name", 
  // shouldn't it be "object dot field name ? "
  fmt.Println(p.Name, p.Age)
}
func main() {
  p := person{"foobar", 23}
  printPerson(&p) // we are sending address to the method
}
```

why can't we execute dereferenced object dot field name instead of address dot field name ? Please read code comments for question explanation, what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p.Name` and `p.Age` work as-is, because if `p` is a pointer to a struct, then `p.Name` is a shorthand for `(*p).Name`. Quoting from [Spec: Selectors:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)

> In the expression `x.f` [...] if the type of `x` is a defined pointer type and `(*x).f` is a valid selector expression denoting a field (but not a method), `x.f` is shorthand for `(*x).f`.

In the light of this, `*p.Name` does not try to dereference `p` and refer to the `Name` field, it tries to dereference the `p.Name` field which is not a pointer.

If you use parenthesis to group the indirection, it works:

```
fmt.Println((*p).Name, (*p).Age)
```

But again, since this form is very frequent, the Spec allows you to omit the pointer indirection and simply write `p.Name`.

Answer (score 3):

In Go, `&` operator is used as a pointer to a variable and holds its address in memory. `*` can be used to “dereference” such pointers. Dereferencing a pointer gives us access to the value the pointer points to.

In your example, When your function receives the argument `&p` (a pointer to variable p), You could change its value directly, as the members `name` and `age` of the struct 'person' are not pointers (*T).

In case, you were to change the members of your struct `person` to pointer type (like in the following example), It would print to console both: pointer values (memory addresses) and the values of var `foobar` and `age` that they point to.

```
type person struct {
    Name *string // Pointer of type string
    Age  *int // Pointer of type int
}

func printPerson(p *person) {
    fmt.Println(p.Name, p.Age) // Pointer values (the memory addresses)
    fmt.Println(*p.Name, *p.Age) // Dereferenced values (foobar, 23)
}

func main() {
    name := "foobar"
    age := 23

    p := person{&name, &age}
    printPerson(&p)
}
```